# Rename command special characters in filename

Tags: rename, filename

I would like to remove [] in multiple file names.
I get an error when doing it with the rename command.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` are special characters in Perl Regex syntax which is used by `rename` command. Use `\` in front them. Example:

```sh
rename "s/\[|\]/_/g" *
```

ie:

```
s replace
[
| or
]
  with
_
* for all files here
```

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you so much. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this command:

```
for file in $(echo *|grep -E '(\[|\])'); do mv $file $(echo $file|sed -r 's/(\[|\])/_/g'); done
```

This will replace all square brackets to underscores in the current directory.